# Is there a consensus on the CaMV 35S minimal promoter sequence?

Tags: gene-expression, transcription-factor

We have an algal enhancer element and a transcription factor that probably binds it. Basal expression of the enhancer element or full promoter driving luciferase in tobacco protoplast was extremely low. I heard this could be overcome by fusing it to a minimal 35S promoter fragment but I can't seem to find a clear sequence for this minimal promoter.The best I could find was on the cambia website where they say it is -90 http://www.cambia.org/daisy/promoters/242/g1/250/264.html

1) Does anybody have experience with increasing the expression of enhancer elements like this? 
2) And what sequence did you use for this?

Comment: Apparently some other plant vectors define it as -46 to +9 relative to the start codon. Even more confused now:
https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=oATyCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA220&lpg=PA220&dq=%22minimal+35s%22&source=bl&ots=WMuuFK7ZSk&sig=exscxB6RpFKTGmSQ3XtR8gNBeP8&hl=nl&sa=X&ei=iXRoVf6mNYiu7gbl0oOABA&ved=0CCAQ6AEwADgK#v=onepage&q=%22minimal%2035s%22&f=false

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody ever has the same question: I found the answer in this paper by Ow et al. 1987 (fig1)
http://www.pnas.org/content/84/14/4870.full.pdf

Just to clarify, I did not want to boost expression of the enhancer element in my algae, it needed boosting in tobacco protoplasts/leaves.